# Is it possible that we can see future if we have mastered dhyan & samadhi?

Tags: samadhi

As I have deep faith in our hindu culture & I am quite very interested in Yoga,Pranayam,dhyan,samadhi & tratak kind of stuff.

I came to know if we have mastered in Dhyan & samadhi , we can be free from all pain & will feel infinite joy & happiness or even In deepest stage of samadhi we can see future also.

Does anyone experienced person know proper methods & way to be mastered in Dhyan & Samadhi?

Comment: No it is not possible. If it was the case the world would knew who that person was.

Comment: Boss it's definitely possible. But too long to explain.

Comment: Boss? Sorry I am boss. Please explain if you think this in possible. @Parabrahman Jyoti

Comment: @Aditya, this entire Universe is just 1 sequence of happening. There's no past present future. Its like for us sun appears to rise in East and sets in west but in truth its not. Same way, Kaala is just 1 sequence of happening. Since we're within the chakra of kala, called "kaala chakra" = it appears as if there's 3 stages of kaala. It may appear but in truth it doesnt exist. So seeing future is nothing but a sequence of this ongoing cosmic drama..Would you say a future is awaiting for hero heroin marriage in a movie? No.Same way distance yourself from the changing reality, you ll get the truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person can find peace & happiness through dhyan & samadhi also even can see future if have mastered.

But for mastering in Samadhi you need proper teacher or guru.

Comment: Welcome MKP To Hinduism SE! When answering the questions on this site it is necessary to add some references in the answer as a support.You can also visit help section of the site to know more about how to write a good answer.

Comment: For instance check out verse no. 9 of Shreemad Bhagvata Purana.It is about seeing future events. You can add this in your answer.

Comment: http://bhagavata.org/canto11/chapter15.html#Text%208-9